# The best way to display taxonomies

Tags: custom-taxonomy, terms

I have a custom hierarchical taxonomy named custom_taxonomy.
For example:

**Term 1**

- term 1_1
- term 1_2
- term 1_3

**Term 2**

- term 2_1
- term 2_2
- term 2_3

I want to display them on the post page as like in example above: name of parent taxonomy and all its childs, then another parent taxonomy and all childs of this one.

Could you please advice the best way to do this. 
I thought to take only parents taxonomies via `get_terms` and then through the loop take childs elements by `get_terms` or `get_term_children`. Only one thing, I don't know how to display only terms related to current post in this case.

Comment: Can you clarify what is a term and what is a taxonomy in your example. Remember, a Taxonomy is the name of the classification. So "Category" and "Tag" are taxonomies, while "Cooking" might be a *term* in the Category taxonomy, while "Baking" might be a child-term of "Cooking". So there's no such thing as a child taxonomy.

Comment: Taxonomy - name_proc. Terms: Cooking - parent, Baking - child term

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been already answered [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/168022/get-taxonomy-terms-for-parent-and-child)

Both the loops needs to exist and you can display it however you like.

```
foreach( get_terms( 'products-category', array( 'hide_empty' => false, 'parent' => 0 ) ) as $parent_term ) {
  // display top level term name
  echo $parent_term->name . '<br>';

  foreach( get_terms( 'products-category', array( 'hide_empty' => false, 'parent' => $parent_term->term_id ) ) as $child_term ) {
    // display name of all childs of the parent term
    echo $child_term->name . '<br>';
  }

}
```

Comment: This is what I did. But in this case will be displayed all terms, instead of display terms of current post

Comment: This was not visible in the question. But here you go. Use $the_post_cat= get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'category' ); Use Your category you want and after that you can display it.

Comment: I've found out. Just need to use 'wp_get_post_terms' instead of 'get_terms'